# Opening NSFG data (from ThinkStats book) with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm going through the book ThinkStats. http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats/nsfg_data.html

I'd prefer to work with pandas because I'd like to strengthen my skill in that, but I'm having a hard time making out how to open this file.

http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats/nsfg_data.html

The usual pd.read_csv(filename) does not seem to work. 
I'm also reading the code provided with the book, but it's a bit difficult to make out for me.

Comment: Have you looked at the data (just in a text-editor)?  It appears to be some kind of fixed width file - so you'll likely need to use `read_fwf` with a mapping of what each column is.

Answer (score 1):

The pandas read_csv function will not work on this data set without some thinking about the data set itself. Indeed, it is neither a comma separated value nor a space separated format.

Instead, it is a kind of home-made format where the number of fields per line is not contant, which is another issue. Besides, number of spaces between values is not constant, which is another issue.

In order to better understand the format of the data files, I would recommend you get the code from the author. The link is provided in the book but it is here http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats/ and to play with the code provided to figure out the format being used

Provided you have the data file, you can use the survey module

```
import survey
preg = survey.Pregancies()
pre.ReadRecors(".")
```